# We want to generate a spark suitable for igniting a potato cannon (alchohol class fuel) preferably without automobile-class coils

Tags: arduino, capacitor, spark, coil

I assume we need about 1000v for a 1mm gap.  I have a coil about 2cm with an iron core, but no idea how big L is.  I have a lot of 330uF capacitors rated for 200v.

What would be a clean way of doing this?  Voltage multiplier with capacitors?
How would we trigger it with the Arduino?  We have been using IRF630 power transistors to turn on power circuits, but those are rated for 200v.

Can anyone suggest a simple circuit to generate a small spark without buying $15 parts from an auto parts store?  If no, tell me and we will buy one...

Answer (score 10):

Get a propane gas BBQ Grill Ignitor.  There are electronic versions, as well as piezo-versions that don't need batteries.  You can buy them at most big box hardware stores like Home Depot or Lowes.

Something like this:  http://amzn.com/B000FJLMOE

Comment: @AnindoGhosh  I was a pyromaniac in a previous life.  Currently, all of my cannons use compressed air instead of something combustible.  :)  I have also used grill ignitors as an ad-hoc ESD testing device.

Comment: @DavidKessner Uh, it was in *this* life, you just lost your memory one day in a big blast.

Comment: @Kaz Well that would explain the scorch marks and the smell of BBQ Pork.

Comment: The problem with this solution, which I already had, is that the Arduino will not have an easy time pressing that button.  The piezo buttons are very hard to push, and building a servo to push it is a kluge.  We would have liked some elegant circuit that would give a spark, but unfortunately, no one has one.

Comment: @Dov  As I stated in my answer:  There are two versions.  A Piezo version and an electronic one.  The electronic one could be easily made to do what you want.  Here, let me Google that for you:  http://amzn.com/B001G7T93A

Answer (score 0):

You might look for one of the high voltage transformers used in the old vacuum-tube televisions, and use it about the same way as an automobile-class coil except with the input voltage in the few hundred volts range.  If you can find an old television, look inside the metal shell with a thick (high voltage) wire going to the picture tube.